# Find most frequent item of a JS array with while loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, while-loop

I have created a function that finds the most frequent item of a JS array with two for loops and displays the item and how many times there is in the array. How can I do it with a while loop?

```js
var arr = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];

//ta = times appeared / m = max / arrchar = array character
var ta = 1;
var m = 0;
var arrchar;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (arr[i] == arr[j])
      m++;
    if (ta < m) {
      ta = m;
      arrchar = arr[i];
    }
  }
  m = 0;
}
console.log(arrchar + "(" + ta + ")");
```

Comment: It is doable but... Why do you need a "while loop"? You don't have any early termination condition, you need to inspect each item once. `for loop` is better suitable for such a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of having a while loop is to use exit conditions. Since there is no exit condition I've essentially created a fairly efficient for loop algorithm and just replaced the for loop with a while loop.

```js
var arr = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];

var occurences = {};

var max = 0;
var champion;

var index = 0;

while (index < arr.length) {
  var item = arr[index];
  occurences[item] = (occurences[item] || 0) + 1;
  if (occurences[item] > max) {
    max = occurences[item];
    champion = item;
  }
  index += 1;
}

console.log(`${champion} has ${max} occurences`);
```

Unfortunately the code above will always consider `3` and `"3"` as the same value. If you do not wish for that to happen then you should use a map instead.

```js
var arr = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];

var occurences = new Map();

var max = 0;
var champion;

var index = 0;

while (index < arr.length) {
  var item = arr[index];
  var newSize = (occurences.get(item) || 0) + 1;
  occurences.set(item, newSize);
  if (newSize > max) {
    max = newSize;
    champion = item;
  }
  index += 1;
}

console.log(`${champion} has ${max} occurences`);
```

Comment: This code will not work correctly if array is [3, 3, '3'], because keys of objects are always strings, this code needs to be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use array reducer:

```js
const arr = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];

let max, winner;

const arrReduce = arr.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  acc[curr] = acc[curr] ? acc[curr] += 1 : 1;
  if(max < acc[curr]) winner = curr
  max = max > acc[curr] ? max : acc[curr];
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(max, winner)
```

Comment: If array would have 1 million elements - how many hours should user wait till such code will finish its work? It needs to be improved

Comment: Hi @DmitryReutov i improved my previous algorithm, what do you think about this new approach ?

Comment: more or less the same code wrote nick zoum above... Please read my comment to his answer, such approach has a flaw also

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter method with the while loop. Create a filtered array for each arr index. If the length of the filtered array is more than the maxOccurence, set the length of the filtered array to the maxOccurence. You can try other array prototype method. There may be a simpler way.

```js
var arr = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];

var char = "";
var maxOccurence = 0;
var i = 0;

while(i < arr.length){
  var filteredArr = arr.filter(x=> x === arr[i]);
  if(filteredArr.length > maxOccurence){
    char = arr[i];
    maxOccurence = filteredArr.length;
  }
  i++;
}
console.log(char + "(" + maxOccurence + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code. It would give you the result which you expecting the most.

const arr = [3, 'a', 'a', 'a', 2, 3, 'a', 3, 'a', 2, 4, 9, 3];

```
// result array
var result = [];

$.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
    if(result[value] === undefined) 
        result[value] = 1;
    else
        result[value] = result[value] + 1;
});

console.log(result);
```